# T-SQL : row_number partion not restarting count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, row-number

I'm using the following code to get a rank for my data. Attached are the results I'm getting vs what I need as a result. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, CR_TS, ROW_COUNT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WQ_WORKED ORDER BY CR_TS) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM 
    #TABLE
```

[Code Results vs Needed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q98Ox.png)

Comment: The partition is working as instructed. You asked for it to increment the row count based on the results of WS_WORKED sorted by CR_TS. As for your target query I'm at a loss how to achieve it.

Comment: Your query and partitioning is working just fine. For each value of WQ_Worked, it is assigning an order value based on the increasing order of CR_TS. Is there a logic you are trying to apply for the expected results? From the given screenshot and results expected, I am not able to see a connection for the way you want the row number to be assigned.

Comment: What he wants is to restart the row-number every time WS_WORKED *changes state*. This is a valid question, as I recently needed to do the same thing. Not to sort by WS_WORKED, but to sort by CR_TS, and then have the row number go up as long as WS_WORKED stays the same, and reset to one each time it changes. Even if it's just going back and forth between two values.

Comment: Yes, I need exactly what pmbAustin mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your image you are wanting to count consecutive WQ_WORKED values when ordered by date.  To do that you first need to establish the grouping (partitioning) criteria in such a way that the desired values are correctly counted.

In this situation you can do that by using the Tabibitosan (traveler) method to identify the groups within your series by first creating a row_number for every record in your record set ordered by cr_ts (and perhaps by another value if a tie breaker is needed), then subtract from that a row_number with the same ordering, but partitioned by the value you want to group by.

This intermediary group id can then be used along with the original partition values to calculate your analytic result.  In this case your final row_count.

With the provided sample data (based on the attached image and expanded data from comment below):

```
Drop Table #TABLE;
with DTA(SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, CR_TS) as (
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 1, cast('6/1/2018' as date) union all
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 1, cast('6/4/2018' as date) union all
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 0, cast('6/5/2018' as date) union all
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 0, cast('6/6/2018' as date) union all
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 1, cast('6/7/2018' as date) union all
  select 7703556, '1817953C1', 0, cast('6/8/2018' as date) union all
  --Expanded dataset below here
  select 7703047, '1648518C1', 1, cast('6/12/2018' as date) union all --0 1 1
  select 7703047, '1648518C1', 1, cast('6/13/2018' as date) union all --2 4 2
  select 7703047, '2010358C1', 1, cast('6/12/2018' as date) union all --0 2 1
  select 7703047, '2010358C1', 1, cast('6/13/2018' as date) union all --2 3 2
  select 7813059, '1648518C1', 0, cast('6/12/2018' as date) union all --2 1 1
  select 7813059, '1648518C1', 1, cast('6/13/2018' as date) union all --2 2 1
  select 7813059, '2010358C1', 0, cast('6/12/2018' as date) union all --2 2 1
  select 7813059, '2010358C1', 1, cast('6/13/2018' as date)           --2 1 1
)
select SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, CR_TS
  into #TABLE
  from dta;
```

The following query returns the expected results (for the original data):

```
with tabi as (
select dta.*
     , row_number() over (order by cr_ts)
     - row_number() over (partition by wq_worked order by cr_ts) grp
  from #TABLE dta
 where shipto = 7703556
)
select SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, CR_TS
     , row_number() over (partition by wq_worked, grp order by cr_ts) ROW_COUNT
  from tabi
 order by cr_ts
```

Results:

```
SHIPTO  NAV_PN      WQ_WORKED   CR_TS       ROW_COUNT
7703556 1817953C1   1           2018-06-01  1
7703556 1817953C1   1           2018-06-04  2
7703556 1817953C1   0           2018-06-05  1
7703556 1817953C1   0           2018-06-06  2
7703556 1817953C1   1           2018-06-07  1
7703556 1817953C1   0           2018-06-08  1
```

With the expanded data set provided in your comment below, you need to add additional partitioning criteria to the various analytic functions:

```
with tabi as (
select dta.*
     , row_number() over (partition by SHIPTO, NAV_PN order by cr_ts)
     - row_number() over (partition by SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED order by cr_ts) grp
  from #TABLE dta
)
select tabi.*
     , row_number() over (partition by SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, grp order by cr_ts) ROW_COUNT
  from tabi
 order by SHIPTO, NAV_PN, WQ_WORKED, cr_ts
```

Comment: Did you get an error? if not then how is it not working?

Comment: So I tried it again and it did work.  When I applied it to my entire data set there are additional sorting that needs to be done so it does not work for the entire data set.

Comment: SHIPTO NAV_PN    WORKED CR_TS       GRP ROW NEED 7703047 1648518C1                 1 6/12/2018 0 1 1
7703047 1648518C1                 1 6/13/2018 2 4 2
7703047 2010358C1                 1 6/12/2018 0 2 1
7703047 2010358C1                 1 6/13/2018 2 3 2
7813059 1648518C1                 0 6/12/2018 2 1 1
7813059 1648518C1                 1 6/13/2018 2 2 1
7813059 2010358C1                 0 6/12/2018 2 2 1
7813059 2010358C1                 1 6/13/2018 2 1 1